# How do you get rid of system files from your home folder?

Tags: macos, filesystems, partition

I have been playing around with the RecoveryHD partition of my mac and mounted it which I *think* has made some system files show up in my home folder. I am not sure but I think it is the case. Now I want to remove these files so I unmounted the partition but they are still there. The file names are things like; root (with a cross sign on it), run, sbin, proc, opt, bin, boot, lost and found (also with a cross sign), library, lib and so on. Here is a pic:

[image: Picture of my home directory]

How would I remove these files without stuffing up my computer?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool copied the system files to your home folder. Like a backup. You can delete them.

Comment: Cool! That's easier than I thought It would be! P.S what do you mean by "tool"?